# The graph shown joins the last point to the first point of my graph how do I avoid that?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNgPx.png)I don't know how to avoid the orange line closing itself

I use this code to read the .txt file and fill the lists

```
with open('P100k-0.2.txt', 'r') as file:
    for i, row in enumerate(file):
        if i == 0:
            continue
        row = row.split(' ')
        step_100k_02.append(float(row[1]))
        s_xx_100k_02.append(float(row[2]))
        s_yy_100k_02.append(float(row[3]))
        e_xx_100k_02.append(float(row[4]))
        e_yy_100k_02.append(float(row[5]))
        p_100k_02.append(float(row[6]))
        q_100k_02.append(float(row[7]))
        porosity_100k_02.append(float(row[8]))
```

and then I use this one to make the graph

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(e_yy_100k_02, s_yy_100k_02, label = 'S_yy_100kPa_0.2')
plt.plot(e_yy_50k_02, s_yy_50k_02, label = 'S_yy_50kPa_0.2')
plt.plot(e_yy_10k_02, s_yy_10k_02, label = 'S_yy_10kPa_0.2')
plt.xlabel('e_yy')
plt.ylabel('Contrainte')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Contrainte vs deformation')
plt.savefig('Fic0.2_control.png')
```

I would like the orange line to be like the other two, that is what I'm aiming for also in some cases the last pooint of the first line goes to the first point of the second line like in the image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4e8q.png)

Comment: Sort the values before plotting